# Is there a way in grep to find out how many lines matched the grep result?

Tags: grep

Suppose I write a `grep` query to find out the occurrence of a method call on an object like this:

```
 // might not be accurate, but irrelevant
 grep -nr "[[:alnum:]]\.[[:alnum:]](.*)" .
```

This would give many results. How to find out how many such results are obtained?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about using `| wc -l` to count the number of result lines?

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
man grep | grep "count"
```

It outputs

```
-c, --count
  Suppress normal output; instead print a count of  matching  lines  for  each  input  file. [...]
```

Comment: I tried grep -cnr but it gave me completely unexpected results.

Comment: It gives the count for each file. By the way, note --only-matching if you want individual matches rather than lines.

Comment: @Daniel, `--only-matching` makes no difference to the behaviour of `--count` in that respect - it still prints the number of matching *lines*.  Yes, that is annoying!

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are OK, I just want to put it into command line instructions in order to have copy-paste versions (from explicit to simplest) for the future:

```
grep --count  "PATTERN" FILE
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
grep -c  "PATTERN" FILE
```

And it is equivalent to:

```
grep "PATTERN" FILE | wc -l
```

As a bonus, below i give you a version where a file with a list of patterns is used.

```
grep -count --file=PATTERNFILE FILE
```

or simply

```
grep -cf PATTERNFILE FILE
```